# Accessing PHP's SOAP Result

Tags: php, soap

I've got a PHP script that accesses a SOAP server and I'm having some trouble accessing the results from the SOAP call.

The following code snippet (I've removed some earlier code that sets up $client1 and an authentication header because I think they're working ok):

```
$output = $client1->GetSingleDiamond(array("DiamondID" => $diamondid));
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDoc->loadXML($client1->__getLastResponse());
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($xmlDoc->saveXML()) . "</pre>";
```

produces the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSingleDiamondResponse xmlns="http://technet.rapaport.com/">
      <GetSingleDiamondResult>
        <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
          <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Table">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="DiamondID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ShapeTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Weight" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ColorTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ClarityTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CutLongTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="LabID" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="labTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="RapNetPrice" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="FinalPrice" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CertificateNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Act_No" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Company" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="COUNTRY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="STATE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CITY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="VendorStockNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="SymmetryTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="PolishTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DepthPercent" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="TablePercent" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="MeasLength" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="MeasWidth" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="MeasDepth" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="GirdleSizeMin" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="GirdleSizeMax" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="GirdleConditionTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CuletSizeTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CuletConditionTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="FluorescenceColorTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="FluorescenceIntensityTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="HasCertFile" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DiamondLocationCountry" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DiamondLocationCity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="FinalPriceCurrency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="LastRate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CurrencySymbol" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CurrencyShortTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
          <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
              <DiamondID>46959935</DiamondID>
              <ShapeTitle>Pear</ShapeTitle>
              <Weight>0.340</Weight>
              <ColorTitle>D</ColorTitle>
              <ClarityTitle>SI2</ClarityTitle>
              <LabID>1</LabID>
              <labTitle>GIA</labTitle>
              <RapNetPrice>337.2800</RapNetPrice>
              <FinalPrice>489.0000</FinalPrice>
              <CertificateNumber>1156352315</CertificateNumber>
              <Act_No>39321</Act_No>
              <Company>CHINA DIAMOND CORP LTD</Company>
              <Name>Darshan Bhagat</Name>
              <Email>info@chinadiamond.com.hk</Email>
              <Phone>852-852-2521 0029</Phone>
              <COUNTRY>HONG KONG</COUNTRY>
              <STATE/>
              <CITY>Hong Kong</CITY>
              <VendorStockNumber>1156352315</VendorStockNumber>
              <SymmetryTitle>Very Good</SymmetryTitle>
              <PolishTitle>Excellent</PolishTitle>
              <DepthPercent>62.9</DepthPercent>
              <TablePercent>56.00</TablePercent>
              <MeasLength>5.96</MeasLength>
              <MeasWidth>3.88</MeasWidth>
              <MeasDepth>2.44</MeasDepth>
              <GirdleSizeMin>Slightly Thick</GirdleSizeMin>
              <GirdleSizeMax>Very Thick</GirdleSizeMax>
              <CuletSizeTitle>None</CuletSizeTitle>
              <FluorescenceIntensityTitle>None</FluorescenceIntensityTitle>
              <HasCertFile>true</HasCertFile>
              <DiamondLocationCountry>Hong Kong</DiamondLocationCountry>
              <DiamondLocationCity>Hong Kong</DiamondLocationCity>
              <FinalPriceCurrency>489.0000</FinalPriceCurrency>
              <LastRate>1.22995001</LastRate>
              <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
              <CurrencyShortTitle>NZD</CurrencyShortTitle>
            </Table>
          </NewDataSet>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
      </GetSingleDiamondResult>
    </GetSingleDiamondResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I need to know is how can I access the data portion?  For example, how would I access the FinalPriceCurrency data, which has a value of 489.0000?

I've tried $output->GetSingleDiamondResult->FinalPriceCurrency but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByTagName`.

```
echo $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('FinalPriceCurrency')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: This works for DiamondID (the very first piece of data) but not for any of the others (i.e. ShapeTitle, FinalPriceCurrency, etc).  I'm not sure what is going on here...

Comment: That's strange. Tested using your sample xml above and it works for any element.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem! I was using __getLastResponse() instead of __getLastRequest()  Thanks for your help!